# Where has django.utils.translation.trans_real.templatize vanished?

Tags: django

The Django 1.11 documentation says it should be there and I checked the github repo and it is not there.

In 1.10.7 it was still there.

Comment: It's documented under `django.utils.translation`, not under `django.utils.translation.trans_real`. The latter is an implementation detail and not part of the public API. `templatize()` is still available in the documented location.

Comment: @knbk Thanks for the comment, I'll let the pypugjs guys know. I was trying to fix a compatibility issue with Django  1.11 there since it blocked my project.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually in `django.utils.translation` instead of `django.utils.translation.trans_real`. (eg. pypugjs needs to be updated)

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest pypugjs release (5.0.1) to have it fixed!